# Initiating Keybindings on a Frame

Tags: java, swing, clojure

I have the following code, intended to add a map of keybindings to a JFrame. Unfortunately, though it compiles and I get no erros when running the program, the bindings do not work.

What am I missing?

```
(defn create-action                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  "Returns an Action that, when called, executes the given fn."                                                                                                                                                                               
  [f]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  (proxy [AbstractAction] []                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    (actionPerformed [e] (f))))                                                                                                                                                                                                               

(defn init-jframe-key-bindings!                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  "Adds the keybindings to the frame.                                                                                                                                                                                                         

   keymap take the form of:                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   {\"KEYSTROKE\" [:key-name fn]                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    ...}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  [frame keymap]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  (let [actionmap (.getActionMap (.getRootPane frame))                                                                                                                                                                                        
        inputmap (.getInputMap (.getRootPane frame) JComponent/WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)]                                                                                                                                           
    (doseq [[keystroke [keyword action]] keymap]                                                                                                                                                                                                
      (.put actionmap (name keyword) (create-action action))                                                                                                                                                                              
      (.put inputmap (KeyStroke/getKeyStroke keystroke) (name keyword)))))
```

The bindings are added like so:

```
  (doto frame 
    (.setFocusable true)
    (init-jframe-key-bindings!                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      {"RIGHT" [:next-view to-next-view]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
       "LEFT" [:prev-view to-previous-view]                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       "T" [:thresh-test conduct-thresh-test]                                                                                                                                                                                                
       "A" [:add-marks #(dosync (ref-set ref-mark-mode :a))]                                                                                                                                                                                 
       "D" [:del-marks #(dosync (ref-set ref-mark-mode :d))]}))
```

**EDIT** The solution was to use `JComponent/WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` in lieu of `JComponent/WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`. I'm not sure why this is the case, as the focus SHOULD have fulfilled the requirement of being an ancestor of the focused components (but maybe not, what with my myriad of components) and still would love to hear an answer, but there's a solution for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

`for` is lazy. Your `init-jframe-key-bindings!` function is being called, and it returns a lazy sequence which, when realized, would actually add keybindings. But you never actualize it; you throw away its results. Instead of `for`, use `doseq` if you want side effects.

Comment: That's an awful mistake, yeesh, but I did catch that (and completely neglected to update my question––to my chagrin) and it didn't solve my problem, unfortunately.